# add debian repository with sed command

Tags: sed, debian

I would like to auto generate my debian system virtualbox with provisionning.
I must install don't standard or default PHP environment.
I must **add repository dotdeb** for find special package PHP for 5.3 version.

**My shell provisionning script must edit /etc/apt/sources.list**
for adding line corresponding to dotdeb repository. This line are :

```
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
```

**How can edit my file with sed command for result this** :

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.11.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160605-17:36]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.11.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160605-17:36]/ wheezy main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main

deb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all
```

The default content file of /etc/apt/sources.list is :

```
#

# deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.11.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160605-17:36]/ wheezy main

#deb cdrom:[Debian GNU/Linux 7.11.0 _Wheezy_ - Official amd64 NETINST Binary-1 20160605-17:36]/ wheezy main

deb http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main
deb-src http://httpredir.debian.org/debian wheezy main

deb http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
deb-src http://security.debian.org/ wheezy/updates main
```

Finally, I just want to add a empty line at the end of file and after add to specific line. But I don't find how add empty line at the end of file and add specific line with multi special character with sed command...

Comment: Not clear, could you please add expected output to your post too?

Comment: Why `sed`? This is an easy job for standard `cat`.

Comment: how do you do with cat command @IporSircer

Comment: @darkomen, is it only a new line you want to enter at last of the Input_file? or any specific line you need to do, please confirm.

Comment: Instead of appending lines to `/etc/apt/sources.list`, you could/should create a new file in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Then you don't need to edit anything, just create/copy the file there. Also makes it easier to remove it later if the need arises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sed -i '$ a\\ndeb http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all\ndeb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org wheezy all' /etc/apt/sources.list
```

Answer (score 1):

If you simply want to add a new line at last of Input_file do following.

```
echo "" >> Input_file
```